# Jquery Validate plugin rules()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a asp.net form where I am trying to use Jquery Validation plugin. I am trying to add the rules using javascript using the rules method. so i tried something like this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').validate();
    $('td [type="text"]').each(function(ind,element) {

        $(element).rules("add", {
            number: true,
            messages: {
                number:"requere number"  
            }
        });
    });
  }
```

Html have css display:none,part marking

```
<td style="vertical-align: middle">
   <input name="1ModalC1.1" type="text" class="input-validation-error">
</td>
```

Class "input-validation-error"appear.But form submited

Comment: your code works fine. do you mean if its empty it still submits?

Comment: When Input display: block everything works fine, but when the display: none does not work.Forms submited

Comment: input is in the model bootstrap, when a modal window is hidden validation does not work

Answer (score 0):

By default, jQuery Validation ignores hidden fields. Therefore you need to set the `ignore` value :-

```
$('form').validate({ ignore: "" }); // default ":hidden"
```

Comment: I have display:none,but not visibility:hidden

Comment: It should be `ignore: []` and @user5555160, makes no difference; `"hidden"` means anything not showing.